# Does "Do I misunderstand something?" sound natural?

Tags: sentence-request

What's the natural way to express that you are not sure if your opposite opinion/conclusion is 100% correct, and politely ask if you misunderstand something.

Does "Do I misunderstand something?" sound natural?

For example:

Alice: "1+1=2"

Bob: "I think it should be 1+1=3, according to ....., do I misunderstand something?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While *Do I misunderstand something?* is not wrong, it's not entirely natural either.

More common expressions that express the same idea are the following:

> *Did* I misunderstand something?
>   *Am I* misunderstanding something?
>   What *don't I* understand?

Answer (score 1):

'Do I misunderstand something' is grammatically correct, however it would be better to say one the following:

- Am I misunderstanding something?
- What am I not understanding?
- Am I not getting right here?
- What don't I understand?
- What am I getting wrong here?

These sound much more natural.